# how to add output data in file directly

Tags: python, file-handling

I am doing a class project and for that I am trying to use a function, where it produce conditional output every time depending on the basis of user input. And I want that output to be store in a file automatically every time it produces the result. Am not sure how to do that. Could someone please help me here. below is the code I am working on:

```
def server_temp(prompt, value_min,value_max):
  while True:
    number_text = input(prompt)
    try:
      number = int(number_text)
    except ValueError:
      print('Invalid number text. Please enter digits.')
      #continue loop and return to the top of the loop
    if number<=value_min:
      print('the room has correct temperature')
      return number
    if number>=value_max:
      print(' the room has very hot temerature ')
      return number
   
#function calling 
server_temp('What is the server room temperature?:',value_min = 21-23,value_max = 24-30)

temp_record= open("room temp record.txt",'w')
temp_record.write('')
temp_record.close()
```

Comment: Googling "Python Write to file" leads to [the relevant part of the Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and also to [some](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) [tutorials](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html). Do these links answer your question? If not, where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach I did googled it but can't seem to find the answer where it tells you to how to add the output into a file automatically. Will have a look on your referred links.

Comment: Seems you're missing out on `continue` in place of `#continue loop and return to the top of the loop`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for ["Append"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

```
 f = open('workfile', 'a')
```

> The first argument is a string containing the filename. The second
> argument is another string containing a few characters describing the
> way in which the file will be used. the mode can be 'r' when the file
> will
> only be read, 'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same
> name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending; any data
> written to the file is automatically added to the end. 'r+' opens the
> file for both reading and writing. The mode argument is optional; 'r'
> will be assumed if it’s omitted.

```
with open("room temp record.txt,"a") as f:
                f.write("\n")
                f.writelines(["Min temp","Max temp"])
```

Comment: not exactly. the above code is writing those line every time it executes. Whereas I am looking to overwrite those lines with the latest output every time it execute. Thanks anyways for helping